# Is there a way to detect changes in a folder using php on both windows and linux?

Tags: php, shell, notifications, directory, multiplatform

I'm looking for a solution to detect changes in folder(s) using **php**. The application may run on both platforms(*linux* and *windows*). I may use different methods for each platform as long as results are the same. 
What I desire is :

1. If a file/folder is added to a directory, I want my app to detect this new file and read its attributes (`size,filetime` etc)
2. If a existing file/folder is saved/contents changed/deleted, I need to detect this file is changed
3. It would be better if I can monitor a base folder outside webroot of *apache* (such as `c:\tmp`, or `d:\music` on windows or `/home/ertunc` on linux)

I read something on `inotify` but I'm not sure it meets my needs.

Comment: This sounds like a task that should be solved outside PHP.

Comment: How quickly do you want to respond to changes?

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher It is not a time critical application actually. I need the list of changes. What is added-removed and what is rewritten.

Comment: You have several examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you are checking compared to the last time you checked rather than just being updated as soon as it changes you could do the following.

You could create an MD5 of a directory, storew this MD5 then compare the new MD5 with the old to see if things have changed.

The function below taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php would do this for you.

```
function MD5_DIR($dir)
{
    if (!is_dir($dir))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $filemd5s = array();
    $d = dir($dir);

    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
    {
        if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
        {
             if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$entry))
             {
                 $filemd5s[] = MD5_DIR($dir.'/'.$entry);
             }
             else
             {
                 $filemd5s[] = md5_file($dir.'/'.$entry);
             }
         }
    }
    $d->close();
    return md5(implode('', $filemd5s));
}
```

This is rather inefficient though, since as you probably know, there is no point checking the entire contents of a directory if the first bit is different.

Comment: This may be useful just to detect the change event. I think I also need the approach mentioned by Panique to maintain the list of changes. Any glitches on my 3rd requirement?

Comment: Monitoring outside of webroot is easy enough with php since it is server side.  Second requirement, instead of doing an md5 on the entire directory, do seperate md5 checks on each individual file, then just keep a directory structure similar in structure but just containing md5 sums.

Answer (score 4):

Monitoring the filesystem for changes is a task that should be solved outside PHP. It's not really built to do stuff like this.

There are ready-made tools on both platforms that can monitor file changes that could call a PHP file to do the further processing.

For Linux:

- [How to efficiently monitor a directory for changes on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788541/how-to-efficiently-monitor-a-directory-for-changes-on-linux) (looks best at a quick glance)
- [Monitor Directory for Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511463/monitor-directory-for-changes)

For Windows:

- [How to monitor a folder for changes, and execute a command if it does, on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/468662/how-to-monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-execute-a-command-if-it-does-on-window)
- The second answer in [How can I monitor a Windows directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904/how-can-i-monitor-a-windows-directory-for-changes)

Comment: Thank yo for your answer also. It lead me to disregard on the fly detection, since it introduces many other techniques especially on Windows platform. I upvote anyway cause it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would

1. scan all folders/files and create an array of them,
2. save this somewhere
3. run this scan again later [to check if the array still looks the same].

As you have the entire data structure from "time 1" and "now", you can clearly see what has changed. To crawl through the directories, check this: http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script and this http://phpmaster.com/list-files-and-directories-with-php/

Comment: Any glitches on my 3rd requirement?

Comment: For the 3rd requirement, just make sure open_basedir is off and PHP can merrily scan all system folders.